# Custom Field - Hide field on Item Edit and Add (ShowInEditForm, ShowInNewForm )

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2007, column, custom-field-types, field-definition

Im using SharePoint 2007. Created a custom field for a SharePoint list, which should not be displayed during Item Add or Edit. I have used SharePoint WSP Builder Project in Visual Studio 2008. Created a custom field type. Is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<FieldTypes>
  <FieldType ShowInEditForm="FALSE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE">
    <Field Name="TypeName">****</Field>
    <Field Name="ParentType">Text</Field>
    <Field Name="TypeDisplayName">****</Field>
    <Field Name="TypeShortDescription">****</Field>
    <Field Name="UserCreatable">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="Sortable">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="AllowBaseTypeRendering">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="Filterable">TRUE</Field>    
    <Field Name="FieldTypeClass">**.**, PDFDisplay, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=****</Field>
    <Field Name="FieldEditorUserControl">/_controltemplates/****.ascx</Field>
    <PropertySchema>
    .
    .
    <PropertySchema>
    <RenderPattern Name="DisplayPattern">
    .
    .
    </RenderPattern>
  </FieldType>
</FieldTypes>
```

Even though the ShowInEditForm and ShowInNewForm is set to FALSE, it is displayed when either adding a new item to the list or when editing an item.

In the Field's Control class's constructor set the two properties to false

```
field.ShowInNewForm = false;
field.ShowInEditForm = false;
```

Still is visible in the edits and item adds..

Answer (score 1):

in sharepoint 2010 => UserControl => CustomFieldControl

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Parent.Parent.Visible = true;
        base.OnLoad(e);
        if (SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode == SPControlMode.Edit ||
            SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode == SPControlMode.New)
            this.Parent.Parent.Visible = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In you element file (and all places where you use `<Field>` element that uses you custom field type) for field definition add `ReadOnly="TRUE"` and it not be displayed during Item Add or Edit:

```
<Field ID="Your field GUID" Name="Your field name" DisplayName="Display Name" ReadOnly="TRUE" Type="Your custom field type" Group="Your field group" />
```

Comment: IN my case i dont use features, just created a field definition in Visual Studio WSP builder project in VS 2008. Edited the field definition to have a ReadOnly="TRUE". `<Field Name="ReadOnly">TRUE</Field>` But still it shows up.Parent field Type was text, changed it to Note..No luck

Answer (score 0):

**ShowInEditForm** and **ShowInNewForm** attributes could be overrided in SharePoint list by ContentType Xml definition in [FieldRef element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa543225.aspx).

If the field is ReadOnly then could be problems with update it value programmatically.